# how ! is different from !=

Tags: c++11, operators

I was writing function which goal is to print list in pair of two, eg:

> list : 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> pair list: 2 1 4 3 6 5

I wrote the following code:

```
printPair(){
    bool flag = 1;
    node *temp = new node();
    node *temp2 = new node();
    temp2 = NULL;

    if(!head)
    {
        printf("Empty List!!");
        return 0;
    }
    temp = head;

    while(!temp && !temp->next)  //Error here 1.
    {
        if(!temp2)  //Error here 2.
            temp2->next->next = temp->next;
        temp2 = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp->next->next;
        temp2->next = temp;
        if(flag)
        {
            head = temp2;
            flag = 0;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

it works fine if  replaced with :

```
1. `while(temp !=NULL && temp->next !=NULL)`
2. `if(temp2 != NULL)`
```

So how is this `!` is different from `!=` ?

Comment: Well, they're two different operators.  What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: when i am using the same code :
1.while(!temp && !temp->next)
2.if(!temp2)
 the output is same as the old list.
eg: 1 2 3 4
output : 1 2 3 4
but if i am changing there 2 conditions with
1.while(temp !=NULL && temp->next !=NULL) 
2.if(temp !=NULL)

it is giving required output :
input : 1 2 3 4
output : 2 1 4 3

Comment: Please see my answers. It explains why you get the following error and the difference between those two operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(!temp){}` will execute when temp has boolean value false.

`while(temp != null)` will execute if temp has any value other than null
(if temp is true, it would also pass)

you want to use while(temp != null) because you follow the -> next references until you reach the last item in the list (temp->next pointing nowhere)